# Read files from USB bulk transfer

Tags: android, ios, usb, google-chrome-app

I am attempting to write a Chrome App that will transfer files from any Android or iOS device plugged into the machine through USB. I'm only working with a Google Nexus 7 and 5 device at the moment. Using the Chrome USB API, I can successfully connect to a device, and I have access to the list of all of its interfaces, and within each interface I have access to a list of all endpoints for that interface. I can claim the interface, and I am about to do a bulk transfer.

I want to find a particular directory that I know the name of, and copy that directory with all of its files and subdirectories, and their files and subdirectories, to the host machine.

But, I'm not sure how to go about it. Which interface do I use? Which endpoint within that interface do I use? I have to pass in the length of the data that I want to read from the bulk transfer, but I won't be able to determine the directory/file size before doing the transfer. How do I know the length of data to read in? Once I get my data back, how do I convert it into a directory/file format that I can then use?

Comment: bulk transwer is just a plain data array of bytes ... so you have to use own protocol ... fx `{{int magic, int headerSize, int filenameSize, byte fileName[filenameSize], int size }, byte data[size]}` ... so you simply read 4 bytes(int) ... if magic is the same then again red 4 bytes for int ... now read headerSize - 8 ... you got whole header ... last part of the header is the actuall file size ... of course you can use some lib like protobuf for such stuff

Comment: So I need to interpret the data returned to find out if it is a directory or a file or whatever? Where can I find the directory/file standard byte formats?

Comment: huh ... you mean like MTP, PTP? over the internat .... but i though that you wana do it by yourself ... MTP should be already implemented in the Android OS itself

Comment: I'm just looking for the easiest and most platform agnostic way to copy files from an Android/iOS device to a host machine running Windows/Mac OS X/Linux. The only way I have found to do it is through a desktop application running from the host machine. The Chrome USB API seems to be platform agnostic and simple enough. I guess I don't understand how I would use MTP. Would I combine the MTP with a bulk transfer? Is there another way to use MTP from a desktop application on the host machine?

Comment: And to clarify, I can't use ADB on the host machine as it requires the user to put their phone into debugging mode

Comment: Is there only one example available online of bulkTransfer performed via the USB API from Chrome? I'm still searching...